# does ClearCanvas RIS take DICOM MWL request?

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

I am looking for a free **RIS** which can take **DICOM MWL** request. I am wondering whether **ClearCanvas** *open source* RIS can do this or not?
Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for a MWL/MPPS Server (SCP) to test your client (SCU) functionalities, you can download our fully functional 60 day evaluation SDK from our LEADTOOLS.com site. This will require access to a SQL Server (express will do) and you can use the PACS Config demo to configure the MWL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ClearCanvas open source RIS does not include a DICOM MWL Server.  The database includes the information for a worklist, but there is not an implementation.  In the DICOM library, there are some support classes available for MWL, but no official implementation.

Answer (score 1):

On github have the project of ClearCanvas(https://github.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas), in this file (https://github.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas/blob/master/Dicom/Network/Scu/ModalityWorklistScu.cs) have a implementation of Modality Worklist, however, I don't know if was fully implemented.

Comment: FYI, this source file is for a Modality Worklist SCU (client), and not for a server.  So, it would not be of use in the context of this question.